# a good software revision control for existing code

Tags: version-control

I'm sure this has been asked before but my question is a little different. I have these files that I'm working with huge data. Some of the data files are more than 2 gigs. I just jumped into this project and all edits have just been on one file. We also have 2 computers and those files aren't in sync all the time. The code is written in IDL using two different versions of IDL. I downloaded Mercurial but was so confused on how to use it because I want to set up a system where if a file is edited we would know about it can why it was edited. Also so we can refer back to it if our program doesn't work anymore. I heard that you can set up a local server and just access the files through there. Is this a good route to go and which program would be easiest? Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of different RCS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software They are all doing their job more or less good. In the end it depends on what fits your needs best.

Answer (score 1):

SVN is the way to go if you're looking for ease-of-use.

Comment: I'd say this is subjective ;) I for example find Git much more easier.

Comment: Can you give me a link to svn please? I googled "svn" and was confused to as which one it is? Also Felix Kling, is Git the one that's online? Thanks!

Comment: You can't go wrong in the case of SVN or Git. There are bridges available.

Comment: If you're on Windows, look for TortoiseSVN. There's also an SVN plugin for Eclipse IDE. Here's a more or less comprehensive list of SVN clients: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients

Answer (score 0):

See [Very large repositories with Plastic SCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820293/very-large-repositories-with-plastic-scm)

Easy to use, and apparently quite fast.    Downsides:  May not be free for your organization if you have over 15 devs

If you do install it, I HIGHLY suggest you read the excellent documentation.   It will show you how to cloak or ignore files you don't want to check for updates each time.